# RxJs 2 Observables: Take first one$ else second$ if empty

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

(FYI: Angular+Typescript)

I have a function that needs to return cheap **Observable 1** if it has anything, otherwise expensive **Observable 2**.

I use **Race** to pick the faster one, but that's not ideal as the **http** calls start then are killed.

```
get(): Observable<Cat> {
    let cachedValues$ = (gets from fast cache)
    let serverValues$ = (gets from expensive server)
    return race(cachedValues$, serverValues$);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use concat to set up a sequence of observables.  Assuming that each of your sources will emit one result and then complete, you can pipe to the **find** operator with the condition that the value isn't empty.

**Find** will return the first emission that passes the predicate and then complete.  It is unique from **first** and **take(1)** in that if the condition is never met the last result will be returned so you always get a result.

```
get(): Observable<Cat> {
    let cachedValues$ = (gets from fast cache)
    let serverValues$ = (gets from expensive server)
    return concat(cachedValues$, serverValues$).pipe(find(x => !!x));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this would work:

```js
get(): Observable<Cat> {
   let serverValues$ = (gets from expensive server)
   let cachedValues$ = (gets from fast cache);

   return cachedValues$.pipe(
      switchMap(value => {
        return value ? of(value) : serverValues$;
      })
   );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using switchMap... I assume what you have is pseudocode.

This will attempt to get from the cachedValues observable, and if the result is falsy it will return the serverValues observable.  Otherwise, it will return the cache result wrapped as an observable, since switchMap must return an observable.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs'

const cachedValues$ = fastObservable;
const serverValues$ = slowObservable;

return cachedValues$.pipe(
  switchMap(cacheHit => {
     if (!cacheHit) {
       return serverValues$;
     }
     
     return of(cacheHit);
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `cache$` is an Observable with 1 or 0 value, you can do

```js
return cache$.pipe(
    first(),
    catchError(() => server$),
);
```

You don't need `first()` operator if your `cache$` already return an error when it has no value.